# Simple EventEmitter not being detected by Parent Component - Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am writing my first Angular2 application with a little help from the angular cli. I am trying to write a show/hide toggle feature for a hamburger menu that is available for smaller screens. My app layout looks like so:

```
|-- app
    |-- src
        |-- navigation
            |-- navigation.component.ts
            |-- navigation.service.ts
            |-- navigation.template.html
        |-- main.ts
        |-- main.template.html
        |-- system-config.ts
    |-- index.html
```

Now I just want a simple feature that when I click a button in my `navigation.template.html`, like so:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" (click)="toggleMenu()">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

the click event invokes a method in my `navigation.component.ts` like so

```
togMenu: boolean = false;
//... more code then,

toggleMenu(): void {
    this.togMenu = !this.togMenu;
    this.navigationService.toggleMenuEvent.emit(this.togMenu);
}
```

that uses a service in the same folder with the following code:

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
    toggleMenuEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Nothing that great but I need the Emmitted value in the `main.template.html` so I listen for the Event Emitter in the `main.ts` file within the class constructor:

```
showMenu: boolean = false;

    constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {
        navigationService.toggleMenuEvent.subscribe(
            (val) => {
                this.showMenu = val;
            });
    }
```

However the event isn't picked up in the parent Component. It isn't heard / recognized, thus the `showMenu` variable is always false. Should I put the name code into the child component the event is heard but it doesn't seem to bubble up to the parent (`main`) component. What I am doing wrong. Please note that I have no errors in my console and I am using the release candidate of Angular2.

I have been looking on this site and other places and the use of Observables are suggested rather than the Event Emitter, I know nothing about Observables hence me doing it this way.

Please note: I have reduced the code in my example so the question is not too long.

Comment: In the `NavigationService` the event is called `toggleMenuEvent`, in your `main.ts` you subscribe to a `showMenuEvent`.

Comment: typo... well spotted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it's a problem regarding the scope of the instance of your service. I mean to have a shared service you need to define it when bootstrapping your application for example:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ NavigationService ]);
```

and not define it again for components in their `providers` attributes. This way you will share the same instance and will be able to share event emitters.

Just a quick note, you should use `Observable` or `Subject` instead of `EventEmitter` in shared services. `EventEmitter`s are only to implement custom events in components.

Comment: I have added the service to the `bootstrap` and I have not duplicated it in the providers attribute of the Components. I will look into using Observables or Subjects instead, I just couldn't / didn't find an example / tutorial

Comment: Perhaps this link for a sample: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service ;-)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the link... Oh and you were right... there was duplication in the `providers` attribute in the main.ts!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes I was astonished because your code looked right ;-)